# hybris smart edit errors

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We have migrated our project from 6.6 to 1811. When I go to smartedit and select Basic edit perspective I am getting below errors. Could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thank you for your valuable time and suggestions.

de.hybris.platform.cms2.exceptions.CMSItemNotFoundException: Content slot not found for name "HeaderContactUsLinks"

de.hybris.platform.cms2.exceptions.CMSItemNotFoundException: Content slot not found for name "HeaderImage"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the jsp associated to this page's template tries to display the **HeaderContactUsLinks** slot by doing the following(or something similar):

```
<cms:pageSlot position="HeaderContactUsLinks" var="feature" element="div">
  <cms:component component="${feature}" element="div"/>
</cms:pageSlot>
```

However, according to the Exception, there is no Content Slot Configured for that position and that is why Smart Edit complains. In order to configure a content slot for that position(i.e **HeaderContactUsLinks**) you can adjust and import the following impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotName; name[unique = true]    ; template(uid, $contentCV)[unique = true][default = 'YourPageTemplateIdGoesInHere']; validComponentTypes(code); compTypeGroup(code)
; HeaderContactUsLinks              ;                                                                           ;                          ; wide

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]         ; name                                  ; active; cmsComponents(&componentRef); ; ;
                         ;                          ; HeaderContactUsLinks-Slot ; Header Contact Us Links Slot; true  ;    ; ; ;

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForTemplate;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];pageTemplate(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true][default='YourPageTemplateIdGoesInHere'];contentSlot(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true];allowOverwrite
                                    ;;HeaderContactUsLinks-SlotForTemplate;HeaderContactUsLinks;;HeaderContactUsLinks-Slot;true
```

Comment: Thank you. First I tried adding the missing content slot names it didn't worked then I  removed the unused contentslotNames from ContentSlotForTemplate then run the impex. it worked.

Comment: Hi DJ, Do you seen below question? have any idea?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594440/smart-edit-unable-edit-the-page-emailsignmodal