# Smart edit unable edit the page emailsignmodal

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Hi Hybris 1811 smartedit I am trying to edit Email Signup Modal but as soon as I click on the link it redirects me to below page. I have multiple sites so sometimes I am getting this warning: WARN  [hybrisHTTP20] [DefaultCMSSiteService] More than one site associated with URL [https://localhost:9002/?site=XXXX]. Returning first. Did anybody faced similar issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have more than one site containing the same **urlPatterns**

This attribute represents a regex that is used by **CMSSiteFilter** to decide the website that will be used based on the URL introduced in the browser or requested by smartEdit(i.e https://localhost:9002/?site=XXXX)

In this case, more than one instances of **CMSSiteModel** were found and the first one was used.

In order to fix this you need to adjust each site to have its own, unique **urlPattern** . If you have apparel and electronics sites, the regexes for both should look like this

```
apparel --> (?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=apparel)(|\&.*)$
electronics --> (?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=electronics)(|\&.*)$
```

This can be changed in backoffice for each and every site:
[image]

Make sure that the preview URL is also changed accordingly so that SmartEdit will know how to perform the HTTP requests for this site:
[image]

Comment: Hi DJ, I already have correct URL pattern. It seems more of a CMS issue. smart edit any pages which user Modal Template as page template I am unable to edit it. On click the link just I am getting the page view itself (like in 2nd screen shot) but no edit options.

Comment: If you go to hac ->  Platform -> Configuration, and search after this property: "smarteditaddon.css.paths.desktop", are you able to see it ?

Comment: Yes I can see this property